# Custom InvalidSessionStrategy is null when SessionManagementFilter is called for session timeout expiration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need a special redirect when session timeout expires. So I am trying to apply custom InvalidSessionStrategy, by using it in filter on SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER level. 
I have the following security configuration

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint"  create-session="ifRequired" >
    <custom-filter before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" ref="customSessionManagementFilter" />
    <custom-filter before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"  ref="customAuthFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/userpage*" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/greetpage*" access="hasAnyRole('USER')" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <headers>
    <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </headers>
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customSessionManagementFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    <beans:property name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="customInvalidSessionStrategy" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customInvalidSessionStrategy" class="com.test.CustomInvalidSessionStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="customHandlerService" ref="customHandlerService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>

<beans:bean id="customHandlerService" class="com.test.CustomHandlerService" />
```

and CustomInvalidSessionStrategy

```
public class CustomInvalidSessionStrategy implements InvalidSessionStrategy {
    private CustomHandlerService customHandlerService;
    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Autowired
    public CustomInvalidSessionStrategy(CustomHandlerService customHandlerService) {
        this.customHandlerService = customHandlerService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String requestUrl = getRequestUrl(request);
        if(requestUrl.contains("/api")) {
            String refererUrl = request.getHeader("referer");
            String redirectUrl = customHandlerService.getRedirectLogoutUrl(refererUrl);
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
        } else {
            request.getSession(true);
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, requestUrl);
        }
    }

    private String getRequestUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();

        String queryString = request.getQueryString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(queryString)) {
            requestURL.append("?").append(queryString);
        }

        return requestURL.toString();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my CustomInvalidSessionStrategy is never called.

From breakpoint in SessionManagementFilter.doFilter() I see that it's invalidSessionStrategy is null, although
SessionManagementFilter.setInvalidSessionStrategy() DID set my custom filter into it.

Will appreciate any advice,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is invalid. the problem was that ajax sent requests to other url, shich wasn't configured to use custom message filter. that is why invalid session strategy was null